# Video hangs while playing on VLC

Tags: 12.04, graphics, video, vlc

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.I am unable to play any video.When I play video on VLC the video freezes and after few min it moves to some other frame and also the sound is breaking.

**PC Details**(From Ubuntu >system setting > details)

RAM 968.5 MiB

Processor AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4000+ × 2

Graphic Unknown

OS type 32 bit

Disk 248.7

Mother Board ASUS M2NPV-VM

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps that you could try. First try resetting your configs to the default:

```
vlc --reset-config --reset-plugins-cache
```

If this does not work try altering the Video Out device used by vlc by going to:

**Tools --> Preferences --> Video --> Output**

and experimenting a little until you find a successful setting. If this does not work try altering the Audio Out device used by vlc by going to:

**Tools --> Preferences --> Audio --> Output module**

and experimenting until you find a successful setting.